# How do I keep the questions in the Multiple Choice divs separate?

Tags: javascript, html, google-apps-script

How do I keep the questions in the Multiple Choice divs separate? When I run the code and select a multiple choice option, I can select multiple of them and when I select one from the next question, it un-selects the options from the previous question. Also, when I enter my email address into the input box and receive the answers, it says 'undefined' for question 6 and 7. Any ideas?

---

Thanks in advance.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<!-- Quiz By Yona Klatchko -->
<html>
  <head>
    <base target="_top">
  </head>
  <body>
  <p class="BoldVerdana">
    Welcome to Yona's Geography Quiz.
  </p>
  <p class="BoldVerdana">
    Begin whenever you are ready. 
  </p>
  <br/>
  <script>
    function RunSend() {
        var Ia1 = document.getElementById("Ia1").value;
        var Ia2 = document.getElementById("Ia2").value;
        var Ia3 = document.getElementById("Ia3").value;
        var Ia4 = document.getElementById("Ia4").value;
        var Ia5 = document.getElementById("Ia5").value;
        var Ma1 = document.getElementById("Ma1").value;
    var Ma2 = document.getElementById("Ma2").value;
        var EmailAddress = document.getElementById('emailAddress').value;
        var result = ("Input questions: 1." + Ia1 + " 2." + Ia2 + " 3." + Ia3 + " 4." + Ia4 + " 5." + Ia5 + "Multiple choice: 1." + Ma1 + " 2." + Ma2);
        google.script.run.send(EmailAddress, result);
        console.log("Quiz complete");
        console.log(result);
        return(true);
    }
  </script>
  <style>
    p.BoldVerdana {
        font-weight: bold;
        font-family: "Verdana";
    }
  </style>
  <br/>
  <font face="Verdana">
    Your teacher's email address
  </font>
  <br/>
  <br/>
  <input type="email" id="emailAddress"/>
  <br/>
  <br/>
  <div id="answers">
    <form>
      <p class="BoldVerdana">
       Input questions
      </p>
      <font face="Verdana">
        Question 1: Which state has a climate suitable for growing citrus fruits — California or Maine?
      </font>
      <br/>
   <br/>
      <input type="text" id="Ia1">
   <br/>
   <br/>
   <br/>
      <font face="Verdana">
        Question 2: The North Atlantic current brings warm waters from the tropics to the west coast of which continent?
      </font>
      <br/>
   <br/>
      <input type="text" id="Ia2">
   <br/>
   <br/>
   <br/>
      <font face="Verdana">
        Question 3: Which Canadian province produces more than half of the country's manufactured goods?
      </font>
      <br/>
   <br/>
      <input type="text" id="Ia3">
      <br/>
      <br/>
   <br/>
      <font face="Verdana">
        Question 4: To visit the ruins of Persepolis, an ancient ceremonial capital of Persia, you would have to travel to what present-day country?
      </font>
      <br/>
   <br/>
      <input type="text" id="Ia4">
      <br/>
      <br/>
   <br/>
      <font face="Verdana">
        Question 5: What is the term for a part of an ocean or sea that cuts far into the bordering landmass and may contain one or more bays?
      </font>
      <br/>
   <br/>
      <input type="text" id="Ia5">
      <br/>
      <br/>
     <br/>
      <p class="BoldVerdana">
        Multiple choice
      </p>
      <font face="Verdana">
        Question 6: The latitudinal differences in pressure delineate a number of major pressure zones, which correspond with
   <br/>
      </font>
      <br/>
      <div id="Ma1">
        <font face="Verdana">
          <input type="radio" name="A" value="larger, more" id="A"/>
          larger, more
          <br/>
          <input type="radio" name="B" value="larger, less" id="B"/>
          larger, less
    <br/>
          <input type="radio" name="C" value="smaller, more" id="C"/>
          smaller, more
          <br/>
          <input type="radio" name="D" value="smaller, less" id="D"/>
          smaller, less
          <br/>
        </font>
      </div>
      <br/>
   <font face="Verdana">
        Question 7: The great Victoria Desert is located in
   <br/>
      </font>
      <br/>
      <div id="Ma2">
        <font face="Verdana">
          <input type="radio" name="A" value="zones of climate" id="A"/>
          zones of climate
          <br/>
          <input type="radio" name="B" value="zones of oceans" id="B"/>
          zones of oceans
          <br/>
          <input type="radio" name="C" value="zones of land" id="C"/>
          zones of land
          <br/>
          <input type="radio" name="D" value="zones of cyclonic depressions" id="D"/>
          zones of cyclonic depressions
          <br/>
        </font>
      </div>
      <br/>
    </form>
  </div>
  <button onclick="RunSend(); document.write('Thanks! Your teacher will recieve your results in an email.')" value="Submit">
      Submit
  </button>
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

The 'name' attribute of the radio buttons really reflects the group. They should be the same within the question set -

```
<form>
  <input type="radio" name="gender" value="male" checked> Male<br>
  <input type="radio" name="gender" value="female"> Female<br>
  <input type="radio" name="gender" value="other"> Other
</form>
```

from - http://www.w3schools.com/html/html_forms.asp